# My ubuntu 17.10 GNOME desktop changed to Cinnamon

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I turned my pc on and logged in via the login screen I always see and now I booted up into a Cinnamon desktop.

I never installed a different desktop and no one has used my pc.
It also mentioned something about updates. Did it switch because the GNOME desktop has to update?

My applications and files aren't gone. How do I roll back?

Edit: there are no other desktops to select in Settings > Themes > Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maybe check if any Cinnamon package is installed, opening up the terminal and typing in the following `sudo apt-get list`. You will get a list, search for any Cinnamon package and then try this: `sudo apt-get purge (package name here) && sudo apt-get autoremove` If that didn't help, you can otherwise just reinstall GNOME with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell` Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a lot of packages installed which contain "cinnamon" it seems

Comment: Try uninstalling them

Comment: I uninstalled `cinnamon` and I am doing an autoremove now. I'll reinstall GNOME. It is so weird how this happened.

Comment: If it didn't help, try reinstalling the system with a live USB, it won't delete every package and/or apps

Comment: This worked, but I am clueless as to why it switched. I am 100% positive I never ran `sudo apt install cinnamon` or changed any settings.

Comment: Probably because something that you installed requires that package!