# Ubuntu Bug style,apps,system everything changed

Tags: system

my Ubuntu 17.10.1 os have run into this bug, icons,style,code etc not working properly,
everything was working fine yesterday, i don't know how this happen. see screenshot below.
**Yesterday**
[image]
**Error**
[image]

**Edit* I installed Resetter software and follow [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/reset-ubuntu-desktop-default-settings) instruction, and finally boot up normal, *warning* remember to backup your data before perform resetting.**

Comment: It looks like cinnamon.

Comment: @Reivax We don't know what it looked like yesterday.

Comment: updated picture, and @pomsky yes it look like cinnamon ubuntu lol.

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008748/my-ubuntu-17-10-gnome-desktop-changed-to-cinnamon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To reset you could first try with this command :**

```
dconf reset -f /
```

To reset your system you can use [Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter).

**CAUTION THIS WILL RESET YOUR UBUNTU SYSTEM COMPLETELY.**

Download :

```
wget https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/releases/download/v2.2.0-stable/add-apt-key_1.0-0.5_all.deb
wget https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/releases/download/v2.2.0-stable/resetter_2.2.0-stable_all.deb
```

Then do following commands in terminal :

```
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi add-apt-key_1.0-0.5_all.deb
sudo gdebi resetter_2.2.0-stable_all.deb
```

[image: Resetter]

Comment: hi, above code give me this error "gdebi error, file not found: resetter_1.0.0-stable_all.deb"

Comment: I updated the download to the latest version. It should work now if you follow the link and commands i edited.

Comment: hi, after i run "Resetter", the app show gray screen i cannot see anything. see here - https://i.imgur.com/UlDItRg.png